# How to make height of OHAttributedLabel scale with content height?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsattributedstring

I use an OHAttributedLabel called demoLbl for displaying text with formatted areas. This label is laid out with Interface Builder and is connected to a property in my ViewController. After setting the attributedText to the label I want all the text to be displayed in the label.
If I don't resize the label then the text is cropped at the end of the label so the rest of the text is missing.

If I use [demoLbl sizeToFit]; then the height of the label is larger or smaller in height than the text (about 10 point, varying with the text's length) thus giving me blank areas at the bottom of my view (after scrolling) plus the width of the label is increased by about 2 points.

If I calculate the height of the original text (NSString) before putting it in a NSAttributedString and adding it to the label's attributedText property then the calculated height is way too small for setting it as the label's height.

Is there a hack or trick I can apply so that the label's height is adjusted according to the NSAttributedString's height?

PS: To be more specific I wanted to add OHAttributedLabel as a tag but it's not allowed to me yet.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm the author of OHattributedLabel.

I made some fixes recently about my computation of the size. Please check it out it will probably solve your issue.

I also added a method named `sizeConstrainedToSize:fitRange:` in `NSAttributedString+Attributes.h` that returns the CGSize of a given NSAttributedString (quite the same way UIKit's `sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:` works, but for Attributed strings and CoreText and not plain stings an UIKit)
Actually OHAttributedLabel's sizeThatFits: calls this method itself now.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot check if your changes work. I was forced to abandon the use of NSAttributedString in exchange of the use of a UIWebView with styled text. May be in some future project I am able to test it. I will contact you if that happens.

Answer (score 1):

You can see if this category gives you a more reliable height.
https://gist.github.com/1071565

**Usage**

```
attrLabel.frame.size.height = [attrLabel.attributedString boundingHeightForWidth:attrLabel.frame.size.width];
```

Comment: It seems that this category is about to do what I want. If I print out the height of the NSAttributedString it shows me a value which could be correct, but if I assign this height to my label, it won't accept it. It's higher than before, but not as high as needed for displaying ll the text. Surprisingly that printing out the height of the label shows me the claculated and assigned height of the NSAttributedString. Dont know where the rror lies.

Answer (score 1):

I added this code to the implementation of the OHAttributedLabel class:

```
// Toni Soler - 02/09/2011
// Overridden of the UILabel::sizeToFit method
- (void)sizeToFit
{
    // Do not call the standard method of the UILabel class, this resizes the frame incorrectly
    //[super sizeToFit];

    CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width, 20000.0f);
    CGRect frame = self.frame;
    frame.size = [self sizeThatFits:constraint];
    [self setFrame:frame];
}
// End Toni Soler - 02/09/2011
```

Thank you Olivier for sharing your code!